# Linux installation analysis

Tags: linux, security, configuration, installation

"[Ending company IT Admin relationship](https://serverfault.com/questions/391985/ending-company-it-admin-relationship)" has a good checklist for taking over an existing IT system, but I'm wondering as it relates to Linux:

- What is the most effective way to assess the scope of existing custom configurations, installs, scripts, etc done?
- Is there any software that will check if the kernel, system files, etc mirror the default files for the version installed?

At this point I don't know what distro of Linux the server (though using [Netcraft](http://uptime.netcraft.com/up/graph) I do know the server appears to be Linux) -- so it's possible without knowing that information that this would be a hard question to answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a tool called [Blueprint](http://devstructure.com/faq.html) which can reverse-engineer an existing system build. Modern package managers also have a means of checking the consistency of packages and displaying which binaries and configuration files have changed (`rpm -vVa` on RPM-based systems).